# How to find all occurrences of a word when not preceded by another?

Tags: regex

How to find all occurrences of a word when not preceded by another? So for example, I want to be able to find all instances of 'sugar' but not 'blood sugar'.

In the following:

> Increase in sugar will cause an increase in blood sugar and any more
>   sugar consumed will ...

The above should make 2 matches and not 3

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the tag description. Not all regex engines are equal, some don't support negative look-around for example.

Comment: What language is this being used in?

Comment: As OP didn't bother to specify the language/flavor, which is essential here, after asked to and more than one day, I vote to close as not a real question.

Answer (score 4):

If your regex language supports negative look behinds, you can use `(?<!blood )sugar` to handle the case without any case sensitive issues.  Depending on the language, you can add a flag to the regex to provide case insensitivity.  This will allow you to find all cases of your condition using any weird combination of upper and lower case letters.  I used your example for testing [here](http://rubular.com/r/3I8UcI8kPe).

The regex is simple, a negative look behind `(?<!blood )` of the string you are looking for `sugar`.  This will match your string only if it is NOT preceded by `blood`.  The space does not need to be returned with the match, so it is included as part of the look behind, instead of before `suguar`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regular expressions to do this. Find-and-replace 'blood sugar' with 'sex magik'. Then you can just search for 'sugar'.

Comment: best find and replace.... ever!